# Unable to connect errors when calling Google APIs (happens most frequently in Drive)

Tags: google-drive-api, google-api-php-client, google-compute-engine

On Friday, I was using the Google Drive API PHP Client version 0.6 and I started getting a lot of errors that looked like

PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_IOException' with message 'HTTP Error: (0) Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4001:c03::54: Network is unreachable

I upgraded to the 1.0 version, but I still get the following:
 (0) HTTP Error: Unable to connect

with failed to open stream: Connection timed out

on various occasions.

Are these errors that are supposed to be caught?  In https://developers.google.com/drive/web/handle-errors there is no mention of IO errors like this...

UPDATE:
Running this all on Google Compute Engine, so I updated the tags in case this is a GCE issue?

Here is my sample code from Friday using the 0.6 client library - where $file_contents is obviously the contents of my file... Seemed like this code was working fine on Thursday and the errors are not happening at regular intervals

(the drive object is passed into a function here):

```
  $file = new Google_DriveFile($drive->files->get($file_id));

      $additionalParams = array(
              'data' => $file_contents
          );
      try{
        $update_result = $drive->files->update($file_id,$file,$additionalParams);
        if($update_result){
          return "true";
        }else{
          return "Error: Could not update file, please try again";
        }
      }catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
        return "Error: Could not create file, please try again (Google Error) " . $e->getMessage();
      } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
        return "Error: Could not create file, please try again (Google Error) " . $e->getMessage();
      }catch (Exception $e) {
        return "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
      }
```

and my updated code using 1.0

```
    include_once 'gapi_php_client_1/src/Google/Client.php';
    include_once 'gapi_php_client_1/src/Google/Service/Drive.php';
    global $session_access_token;
    global $session_expires_on;
    global $session_refresh_token;
    global $client_id;
    global $client_secret;

    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google+ PHP Starter Application');
    //// Visit https://code.google.com/apis/console?api=plus to generate your
    //// client id, client secret, and to register your redirect uri.
    $client->setClientId($client_id);
    $client->setClientSecret($client_secret);
    $client->setRedirectUri('postmessage');
    $client->setAccessToken($session_access_token);
    $client->refreshToken($session_refresh_token);

    try{

      $file = $drive->files->get($file_id);
      $additionalParams = array(
              'data' => $file_contents,
                'uploadType' => 'multipart'
          );
      $update_result = $drive->files->update($file_id,$file,$additionalParams);

    }catch (Google_ServiceException $e) {
       $file_save = false;
    }catch (Google_IOException $e) {
      $file_save = false;
    } catch (Google_Exception $e) {
      $file_save = false;
    }catch (Exception $e) {
      $file_save = false;
    }
```

Comment: What does the code look like that throws your original `IOException`? Seems like you're attempting to reach an IPv6 address of `2607:f8b0:4001:c03::54:`, and maybe there's an issue somewhere with trying to hit that address.

Comment: What's the exact line that throws the original `IOException`?

Comment: Well, it's not in this code, it's in the PHP Api Client Library - Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:4001:c00::5f: Network is unreachable' in gapi_php_client/src/io/Google_CurlIO.php:123 that's the old version... in the new one it's gapi_php_client/src/Google/IO/Stream.php at line 118... if the response is false then it will just throw an error

Comment: Really not sure. That IPv6 address appears to belong to Google, so that seems expected. Something in your environment may not support IPv6, possibly.

Comment: Yes, that is what is confusing... My environment is Google Compute Engine and I don't know why it would fail randomly.  Also the ipv6 address was when I was using curl - I still get strange errors from the APIs when using file_get_contents that are just Unable to connect using the 1.0 version of the API.  I just got this for cloud sql as well, so I guess it is just a general API issue or my environment

Comment: And without any change on my part, I seem to not be getting any issues anymore.

Comment: I think the answer is "Google be crazy".

Answer (score 0):

You can also face this error if using fiddler or wireshark behind the scene.....go to task manager and kill fiddler / wireshark

It worked for me....