# Why do calls to Google APIs from Compute Engine fail intermittently with error "Network is unreachable" and an IPv6 subnet?

Tags: google-cloud-datastore, google-compute-engine, google-api-php-client

Some calls to Google APIs made from Google Compute Engine instances fail intermittently with the error message:

```
cURL error 7: Failed to connect to 2607:f8b0:400c:c0b::5f: Network is unreachable (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html)
```

I'm encountering this error intermittently when trying to access Datastore, but [other people have encountered this error calling other Google APIs from Compute Engine instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21535844/unable-to-connect-errors-when-calling-google-apis-happens-most-frequently-in-dr). The error seems to occur when we are making multiple calls to the Datastore API in a short period of time (though the instances are otherwise not highly utilized). There are no other indications of problems for other services running on the same VMs at the time of these errors.

The call is being made from CentOS 7 VM instances running PHP code on Apache using Google's PHP SDK. The VMs do not have public IP addresses. Most of the time, we can access Datastore and other APIs from the same VMs without problems, so we know that the network and VM configuration are correct.

Specific sub-questions:

- What causes these errors?
- Why are we getting a "Network is unreachable" error, instead of a meaningful error message from Datastore?
- Why is there an IPv6 subnet in the error message? We haven't enabled IPv6, and [Google doesn't seem to support connecting to Google APIs and services from an external IPv6 address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/configure-ipv6-address#limitations).

Comment: Did you reach by chance any quota limits during those moments?

Comment: @JavierA How would I determine that I reached quota limits at a certain time?

Comment: My previous idea was based on "multiple calls to the Datastore API in a short period of time " although the message you obtain may not be related with a quota limit. Are you accessing directly from the GCE instance to the API? Have you been able to find any related logs at the network level?

Comment: Have you been able to find more info on this? We're starting to see the exact same thing with Cloud Storage under a new project. The same code was used in a different project and things seem to work fine there. The only difference I could think of is the VMs are in different regions (us west vs us central) and the storage buckets differ a bit there too (the new project uses dual region buckets, while the other uses multi region).